# Recommendation on howto avoid GC delays in a Client Application

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

let us imagine this simple test programm:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var length = 30000000;
    var c = new List<object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        c.Add(new object());
    }
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    Console.WriteLine("GC took " + (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

On my computer (Framework 4.0, x64) the output is ~1.4 seconds while the sample consumes ~1GB of RAM.

Question: Is there any way to accelerate garbage collection? Any best practice? Memory consumption of ~1GB in a Client App is much, but still rather reasonable. But delayes of >1 second are under my circumstances not acceptable.

Just ideas that probably won't be supported but could help me:

- Can I tell the GC to ignore some objects?
- Can I split the heap into multiple parts in order to have GC runs over parts of the heap. (I'd prefere ten times 100ms delay.)

Comment: How the the GC collect anything if you still have references to all 30 million objects in that list??? Also that list will probably end up in the LOH, so you pretty screwed from the start.

Comment: @leppie even if the list *does* end up on the LOH: if the list is a list of references, you still have all the *objects* on the regular heap. Also: the problem of the GC not actually collecting anything can be the most annoying part of this issue: since it doesn't collect anything, you're likely to see a regular series of spikes over time as GC triggers and does nothing useful.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Say you `null` the list and the list still stays in the LOH. Does the actual references then become eligible for GC? Or will the list still hang onto them?

Comment: In the listed code, the GC is not supposed to collect anything. It is a radical siplification of the situation in my current project where are many objects that must survive GC.

Comment: @leppie yes, the references of the contents are then eligible. The list itself might have delayed GC due to the LOH, but that doesn't mean that anything "in" the list is delayed, because ultimately nothing is "in" the list except for the references themselves. If the list isn't rooted, then: *the list isn't rooted*

Answer (score 4):

In some cases when working with very large amounts of data that are *going to be uncollectable* for a considerable amount of time, then GC can be annoying - there will be lots of references, and even worse: the GC isn't actually likely to collect much of it, so the time is wasted! One option here can be to *consider* using arrays etc of *value types*. The significance here is that an array of 2 million value types is only one reference; the 2 million *values* don't have any impact on collection. However, sub-references will still have an impact, for example `string`s per row. But it [*can help*](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmarcgravell.blogspot.com%2F2011%2F10%2Fassault-by-gc.html&ei=H8oYUbieGsaM0AXGg4HABw&usg=AFQjCNFSyABVYom6-Ckf9MnpKLDEbV0Ifw&bvm=bv.42080656,d.d2k).

Since I mentioned `string`s, another thing to look at there is whether you have multiple instances of the same underlying combination of characters; for example, via loading data from a database or file. You might consider applying some manual string interning there (**not** using `string.Intern` - but a per-load dictionary or similar). This will again reduce the number of `string`s that are in play for collection.

As a final thought; if your data requires collections, that can be tricky - for example a list typically involves an extra 2 objects: the list and the underlying array. Multiply that by a few million and things can start getting tricky. In *our* case, we got around that by using fixed buffers, but that is a bit of an advanced topic, and only applies if you have a predictable and small "cap" on the number of items in the list.

Comment: Why do you recommend against using `string.Intern()`? Because it would mean that string is never GCed?

Comment: @svick just because you don't necessarily want all those strings forever; they are usually contextual to a particular "load" of data. No need to swamp the global interner.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is completely artificial - in practice you would not be explicitly waiting for GC to complete in your application.

However, if you have certain time-critical sections of code, then you can [disable GC temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005865/prevent-net-garbage-collection-for-short-period-of-time).