# Does garbage collection affect performance?

Tags: performance, garbage-collection

I am just reading about the performance of several programming languages, and I noticed that garbage collection gets mentioned fairly often. Does garbage collection affect the performance of a language at all? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind here is a language without garbage collection must still both allocate and free objects. Garbage collection allows the "free" part of the cycle to happen in batches, and at times when the application is otherwise relatively idle. In an environment with minimal memory constraints, most collections might even defer until the program is completed. In other words, a highly-efficient garbage collector has the potential to be *faster* than the common practice in a traditional platform... not that we're quite that far yet, but this is improving all the time.

The trick is when garbage collections do occur, the collector must still spend resources doing the analysis of what is reachable and what isn't, or what has a reference count > 0 and what doesn't (depending on the type of collector). That is a real performance penalty. Additionally, this process does tend to briefly interrupt normal execution.

The interruptions can especially be a significant factor in applications that are sensitive to latency issues. This happens to include the common scenario of serving web content. Fortunately, there are also now garbage collector modes to reduce this impact.

The result is for most garbage collected platforms, the collector is one factor to consider when evaluating performance. The *net effect* of the garbage collector may be minimal — or even a net positive! — over the life of an application session, but there can short-lived periods where there is significant negative impact, and it's important to be aware of how to mitigate those issues.

---

The above is all platform agnostic. Personally, I'm most familiar with the .Net environment. In that specific area, and talking specifically about the web service challenges mentioned previously, the things to know are to make sure you're using the GC's server mode, that you're up-to-date with the latest version of the framework (there is lots of on-going performance work that has born some fruit in this area in recent releases), that you avoid the large object heap as much as possible, that you do whatever you can to reduce allocations in the first place, and that you have appropriate monitoring in place.

Answer (score 3):

It mostly depends on the language/runtime.

In some implementations, the GC can pause your application (suspend the threads), and then perform a collection, hence the performance problems.

Some implementations perform optimizations that let your code run while the GC is collecting unreferenced objects. For instance, the [.Net GC can be tuned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357(v=vs.110).aspx) to use different collection modes and object heaps, and you also can [give it a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005865/prevent-net-garbage-collection-for-short-period-of-time) not to run in performance sensitive regions of code.

I can't really give more details as all of this is implementation specific. But I should mention that language runtimes most often try to optimize their GCs really hard, and most of the time you won't even notice it's there. It can become a problem though in very specific cases, and hopefully there's a possibility to work around that to minimize the GC pressure.

Comment: To add to this: .Net optimizes things be separating _collection_ from _compaction_. The GC can do it's thing while other threads are running, because it handles consolidating the memory holes as part of a separate process, and therefore isn't going to move an object out from under another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is a mechanism to clean unused object to free resource allocation, the garbage collector works base on an robust algorithm to allocate which object should be clean and which not. This process is resource consuming so it is always advice that developer should explicitly release or clean up unused object.

Using proper collection should be consider to improve performance and resource consuming of application. Strong-typed and array are always have high priority to use to avoid boxing/ unboxing as well as reduce resource costing to manage the collection.

Please refer to using Array, ArrayList, HashTable.