# disable momentarily GC for critical section code

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, real-time, critical-section

i'm trying to write a realtime application (with physical interaction) with c# language. Globaly it work fine, but sometimes my criitical section has to be late and this is not pretty good. i'll suggest my GC is involved in first time.

i use actually default parameters c# (GC is active, prog is not pre-jitted, i don't use marshall, etc).

can i disable momentarily the GC activities (i know it work in async parallel thread) for my critical code section or maybe something like it ?

or should i to says to my GC to do not manage my critical section ?

i'm open to any request and remarks thanks !

edit : my prog is always on real-time.

Answer (score 0):

This question might help you. [Prevent .NET Garbage collection for short period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005865/prevent-net-garbage-collection-for-short-period-of-time)
Also, what makes you think that GC is responsible for the lateness?
I also would like to say, that you might want to use structures, since they are stored in stack, so they are not affected by GC and generally are faster.

Comment: i doesn't see this article but i was seen that [MSDN low latency mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx). i know GC is faster but went is was called he stop all thread, you can see that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). it's possible my problem is different and GC is not in charge.

Comment: Well, I've provided you with answer on how to suspend GC. If you want the community to find the origin of you problem you should post code examples

Comment: @FlorianJ Note that in .NET 4.6 they added two new methods for this: [`GC.TryStartNoGCRegion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.trystartnogcregion.aspx) and [`GC.EndNoGCRegion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.endnogcregion.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i can't post an exemple of code now, but can i have mre precision to how to do this ? The critical section should be mandatory into a try-finally ? how long the GC was correctly setted to low latency mode ? i don't use any struc on my app

Comment: oh well @xanatos,  don't know this, i'll looking for more information to .NET 4.6, thanks !