# C# how to reduce garbage collection

Tags: c#, performance, garbage-collection

I am writing a simulation which has an update loop that's called every frame. In the update function, I have millions of objects to update, so it looks like this.

```
public void Update(float deltaTime)
{
    Time += deltaTime;
    foreach (SimulationObject obj in objects.ToArray())
        obj.Update(deltaTime);
}

where objects is
List<SimulationObject> objects = new List<SimulationObject>();
and is populated at program initialization time.
```

You can probably see objects.ToArray() makes a copy of this huge list every frame then the copy gets garbage-collected. This causes huge performance issue for me. For a run of about 2 minutes, the garbage collected reaches about 2G. Since the list of this objects is being asynchronously modified in the background by some third-party library, it seems I can't remove ToArray().

I am wondering if there's a good way to reduce garbage collection, either avoid copying or reuse the allocated space?

I am new to C# and tried searching for answers, but was not able to. If this is a duplicated post, I apologize.

Comment: FYI .ToArray() makes a copy of the collection though the objects in the collection aren't copied http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,783a052330e7d48d

Comment: Please see the answer at: [Prevent garbage collection for a short period of time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005865/prevent-net-garbage-collection-for-short-period-of-time)

Comment: @Eminem - assuming `SimulationObject` is a `class` (reference type), not a `struct` (value type).

Comment: It's hard to imagine, how exactly you reach about 2 GB of garbage that fast. If `SimulationObject` is a `class`, then you just copy references. Not sure, how that could accumulate so fast. - about reusing, you *could* have a local (on class level, outside the `Update` method) `List<SimulationObject>` that cannot be modified from elsewhere and then `localList.AddRange(objects); /* do stuff */ localList.Clear();`. In theory, you will only ever have a maximum of two lists of references to all the objects.

Comment: _"the list of this objects is being asynchronously modified in the background"_ -  generally you want to avoid using threading in games/simulations for _fine-grained_ operations such as this.  Consider using two lists - a _pending_ (one that is being worked on in the background) and an _active_ list (for `Update`).  Then flip them around when the time is right.  http://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Architecture-Jason-Gregory/dp/1568814135

Comment: @MickyD - that actually sounds like the best way to go.

Comment: You can also take a leaf out of XNA where some many fine c# performance tips were suggested to minimise GC impact (which was particularly important for c# heritage Xbox 360 games).  For example there is a measurable expense in a simple `foreach`!  Check out [Shawn Hargreave's blog (Microsoft)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/) as  well as [Riemer's XNA Tutorials](http://www.riemers.net)

Answer (score 2):

`ToArray()` is not really necessary here, it is just a waste of time and memory. Use the `for` loop. I would start with something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++) 
{
    SimulationObject obj = null;
    try 
    {
        obj = objects[i];
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) 
    {
        // something was removed from the collection
        // we reached the end of the list
        break;
    }

    obj.Update(deltaTime)
}
```

This code splits `obj = objects[i]` and `obj.Update(deltaTime)` intentionally in order to avoid interrupting the loop if `Update()` throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Be aware of two facts:

- Some objects will skip the first iteration after they have been added to the `objects` collection, which should not actually be a problem, as their addition is asynchronous by design.
- Some objects will probably be updated just once after they get deleted from `objects` list (naturally, *simultaneously* with deletion, but the outcome tends to appear like it happens "after"). Depending upon the simulation this case can be undesirable and will probably require some specific handling.

Comment: This actually circumvents that exception (while maybe catching a different exception). This probably does the job.

Comment: Whoops my bad.  I think it would be better if the OP used thread-safe collections in the first place or maintained two lists.

Comment: If you loop in reverse, the likelihood of throwing an exception is reduced significantly.

Comment: @egrunin `objects.Count` is checked on every iteration, so looping order does not make a difference, moreover in the reverse case exception will break the loop on the furst iteration, not after the last one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to call `ToArray()`, so you can just use

```
public void Update(float deltaTime)
{
    Time += deltaTime;
    foreach (SimulationObject obj in objects)
        obj.Update(deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: This will throw an [InvalidOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) - "collection was modified" - if another thread modifies the collection while looping over it, like OP said was a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out you dont need to use toArray() method since it will just create the copy of your current list.

If I understand correctly you are doing this since your list is being modified by third party lib in the background.

I think you could safely use Parallel.ForEach loop in this case, since you are not modifying list itself, only items in the list.

```
      Float Time; // some value
      Float deltaTime; // some value
      Parallel.ForEach(objects, currObject =>
            {
                // do stuff
             Interlocked.increment(ref Time,deltaTime);
             currObject.Update(Time)
            }
```