# There is RTSJ for Java - Is there something comparable for C#?

Tags: c#, java, real-time, rtos, rtsj

I read that there is a realtime specification for a virtual machine executing java bytecode in real-time (RTSJ 1.1 in JSR 282). This makes it possible to execute Java code in real-time even on embedded devices with an RTOS like OS9 or WinCE.

Since I like C#, I was wondering if there is such a specification for C# also? Of course it makes no sense running this C# runtime from within Windows, but maybe there are some projects going on in the Mono camp? This would be a big market for C#. Do you agree?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no parallel to RTSJ to date for C#.  Some academic work (surprise!) on the topic, however:

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1052666

And some [halfway industrial interest](http://www.eurotech-inc.com/info/white-papers/Managed_Code_for_Real_Time.pdf) which doesn't appear to go the full way to real-time.

Note the related (but not very helpful) discussion on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165201/deterministic-gc-in-the-clr).

Given that RTSJ has struggled to get traction, I'm not sure what the demand for a very similar .Net equivalent might be.  Perhaps as RTSJ gains credibility, the promise of increased productivity for modern languages in the time-critical world will grow and produce pull for a real-time C#/CLR.

Comment: I also read this "halfway" thing but this is a very special case. It does not cover e.g. the parameter passing to methods that would leed to temporary objects that the GC would clean up at some time. I just found this: http://www.kw-software.com/com/products/2307.jsp which looks very interesting if it works. My demand would be to do machine automation with C#.