# How can I prevent garbage collection from being called when calling ShowDialog on a xaml window?

Tags: c#, performance, xaml, memory

I have a application that's using a lot of memory, but for now I cannot change this fact.  My problem is that I have an operation I'd like to perform and provide a progress dialog but it appears that displaying the xaml progress window is causing `GC.Collect` to be called 10 times!  Any ideas how I can optimize opening my progress window?

According to my Ants Profiler the calls leading up to GC.Collect are

```
System.Window.ShowDialog() ->
..
..
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CreateCachedBitmap ->
SafeMILHandle.UpdateEstimatedSize ->
SafeMILHandleMemoryPressure.ctor ->
MemoryPressure.Add ->
MemoryPressure.ProcessAdd ->
GC.Collect
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to overclock my CPU? Probably not, since you don't even know what kind of hardware I have. Likewise, it's hard to optimize code that you can't see. Post your code.

Comment: The call stack that leads to the garbage collection is all .NET assemblies so I don't know what part of my code would be worthwhile posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a solution that would completely disable the bitmap image related memory pressure and subsequent garbage collection. It is more of a hack, but you can read about similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774663/elementhost-size-causes-slow-wpf-open-load-with-high-memory-usage).

```
typeof(BitmapImage).Assembly.GetType("MS.Internal.MemoryPressure").GetField("_totalMemory", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, Int64.MinValue / 2);
```

This way you avoid searching all over your code to find and modify WPF icon initialization. On top of that some controls like `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost` will implicitly add bitmap related memory pressure regardless of how you initialize.

Comment: Warning! This does not work with the latest .Net 4.6.2 (release 394802 / 394806). MemoryPressure class no longer exists and AddPressure and RemovePressure have been moved into GC.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Please let know on how to get over this problem in .Net 4.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Have you check other stackoverflow questions related to the topic? There might be some hints you can use:

[How to avoid garbage collection in real time .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85283/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection-in-real-time-net-application)

Comment: I tried adjusting the latency mode, but it didn't help in this situation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug/feature in WPF:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687605/gc-is-forced-when-working-with-small-writeablebitmap

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/MS/Internal/MemoryPressure.cs

EDIT: Since .NET 4.6.2 the MemoryPressure class has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collection was caused by the initialization of the WPF icon.  When I removed the icon property from the xaml:

```
<Window ... Icon="/CommonUI;component/Common/ProgressReporting/MyIcon.ico">
```

and instead initialized it in the constructor:

```
public ProgressWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Icon = Properties.Resources.MyIcon.ToImageSource();
        }
```

the problem went away.

The difference that `System.Window.UpdateIcon()` is no longer called during `ShowDialog()`.  The `UpdateIcon()` call was creating a `CachedBitmap` for each image size in the icon file which in turn was calling `MemoryPressure.Add` and due to the high memory usage of the application was calling `GC.Collect` for each new bitmap created.

This small change has reduced the loading time of my progress dialog by 15s when a large project is loaded in the application!